# Por qué al hacer click en el boton se activa un color en el borde

Tags: javascript, css, html5

tengo una duda por qué al momento de hacer click en el botón se marca el borde de color, qué propiedad debo modificar para que no se siga viendo, saludos y excelente día a todos :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando css puedes desacerte de ella asi:

```
button {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó :D y ahora se ve mejor mi botón :D gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Es una característica de accesibilidad, hace notar el enlace, input o botón que tiene el foco, ya sea un click sin acción predeterminada o navegando sin mouse con teclado (la tecla TAB generalmente).

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms

> 2.4.7 Focus Visible: Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible. (Level AA)